# MS Excel automatically changes cell variables

Tags: excel, autofill

I'm using the formula 
`=Lookup(B2,Sheet2:D2:Sheet2:D9,Sheet2:A2:Sheet2:D9)` 
to search the value of B column in current Sheet in Sheet2's D column and then return the value of Sheet2's A column in the same row. When I expand lower corner of the cell to autofill 500 cells vertically, I see Excel has incremented B2:B500 as well as D2,D9,A2,A9 (those of Sheet2) as well. I don't want the latter to happen. In fact I want Excel **NOT TO CHANGE**  D2,D9,A2,A9 in the formula. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is to do with the difference between relative and absolute references.

Relative references change when you copy a formula from one cell to another. If you enter `=A1` in B1 and copy it to B2 it will now be `=A2`.

Absolute references don't change when you copy them. Enter `=$A$1` in B2, then copy it to B2 and it will still be `=$A$1`

A "$" before the column reference anchors the column. A "$" before the row reference anchors the row. A $ before both anchors a specific cell.

Comment: It worked when I used absolute referencing the way you told. <br> **Thank you so much!**

Comment: Also, when entering a formula, after entering an address you can press F4 to cycle between relative, absolute, absolute row, absolute column and then back to relative.

Comment: By the way I didn't get the last paragraph of your answer, anchoring a row or column

Comment: @MahdiHaghgoo If you enter `=$A1` in B1, then column **A** is **"anchored"**.  If you drag B1 to the right, all the created formula are `=$A1`. If you drag B1 down, the row numbers will change because the row reference is **not anchored** (i.e. the row numbers don't have a "$" before them).